# VBA - Set Range Between Two Dates Using Search Function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get my VBA code to search through a column for a user-inputted value (on a form) and set a range based on the values.

I need the code to scan DOWN through the column until it finds the value (which is a date) and then scan UP through the column to get the second part of the range. I need it to be like this because there might be multiple instances of the same date and they all need to be accounted for.

I've tried this:

```
StartRange = ws.Cells.Find(What:=StartDate, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)

EndRange = ws.Cells.Find(What:=EndDate, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

But it's not working the way I had expected and is erroring. (Edit: the WS has been defined, so I know that's not the issue). I don't even know if I'm going about this the right way

I'm feeling defeated :(

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I've yet to try any of the suggestions as I am away from my project at the moment, but I feel I need to clarify a few things.

1. The dates will always be in chronological order, I have a script that organises them on sheet activation
2. I need to be able to error handle dates that do not appear in the database, I also need the script to be able to "skip over" dates that don't exist. Ie, 1st 1st 1st, 3rd, 3rd, 5th. If my start and end dates were the 1st and 5th, the entire example would be the range.

Thanks for your help so far guys though, I appreciate it!

EDIT2:

I've tried a few answers and have added this in to my code, but it is now failing on a Range_Global fail.

```
Dim startrange, endrange, searchrange As Range
LookUpColumn = 2

With ws.Columns(LookUpColumn)
    Set startrange = .Find(What:=Me.R_Start.Value, _
      After:=ws.Cells(.Rows.count, LookUpColumn), _
      SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)

    Set endrange = .Find(What:=Me.R_End.Value, _
      After:=ws.Cells(5, LookUpColumn), _
      SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)

    searchrange = Range(startrange, endrange)

MsgBox searchrange.Address
End With
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: as I understand this, the "StartDate" and the "EndDate" are distinct. Q1: Can these 2 be inputed with the same value? Q2:The search column contains more than once both the StartDate/EndDate, just one, which one? Draft Solution: I would tackle this with a `for i=1 to X`, stop when I hit the "EndDate", store i's position and then `for j= (i's position) to 1 step -1` and stop when I hit the "StartDate". I will write the code but I need more details.

Comment: @Takedasama Thanks For Replying. Q1) Yes, the dates can be the same and the range will need to select all dates that are the same. Q2) The search column could contain multiple entries of both the start and the end date, for example: 1st, 1st, 1st, 2nd, 2nd, 3rd, 3rd. with 1st and 3rd being the start and end dates. I'd need all of the example in the range. Thanks. Oh and thanks for your draft, the only thing is is that i could have the potential to be sifting through 30,000 rows of data, so I to X could be very memory intensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with this and see what needs to be fine tuned.
This code will look for a date (based on input) and **find the position of that date in a column**. Same with the "EndDate" and then **creates a range on that column between the 2 positions**.

```
Sub ARange()
Dim Sh As Worksheet: Set Sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i, j As Integer

LookupColumn = "A" 'Define the LookupColum / If you find using column index to be simpler then you need to switch the search from (range) to (cells)
StartDate_Value = Sh.Range("B2").Value 'Use whatever you need to define the input values
EndDate_Value = Sh.Range("C2").Value 'Use whatever you need to define the input values

For i = 1 To 30000
    If Sh.Range(LookupColumn & i).Value = EndDate_Value Then EndDate_Row = i
Next i

For j = EndDate_Row To 1 Step -1
    If Sh.Range(LookupColumn & j).Value = StartDate_Value Then StartDate_Row = j
Next j

Dim MyDateRange As Range: Set MyDateRange = Sh.Range(LookupColumn & StartDate_Row & ":" & LookupColumn & EndDate_Row)
MsgBox "MyDateRange = " & LookupColumn & StartDate_Row & ":" & LookupColumn & EndDate_Row
End Sub
```

Another approach should imply looking for the EndDate from bottom upwards (as in Excel's column values) and for the StartDate from top to bottom. like this:

```
For i = 30000 to 1 step -1
For j = 1 To 30000
```

And the 3rd (the charm):for the EndDate from top to bottom and for the StartDate from top to bottom. like this:

```
For i = 1 to 30000
For j = 1 To 30000
```

And the 4th (The One):

```
For i = 1 to 30000
For j = 30000 to 1 Step -1
```

On my home laptop the search on the 30.000 cells is instant (under 1s).
Give it a try and based on the feedback we can fine tune it.

On the Other hand, I might read your question as for looking To select not all values between the top / bottom position, but any cells with values of dates between the 2 input values **neverminind the arrangement of the values within the list (column cells)**. i.e. If StartDate = 1.Jan.2013 and EndDate = 3.Jan.2013. The code should pick up 1,2 and 3 from the 30.000 list neverminind the position of these 3 dates (which in fact may be found thousands of times). If This is true, the solution may be simpler than the one above.

Comment: You should change `Dim i, j As Integer` (i is declared as a Variant and j will fail if it is > 32767) to `Dim i As Long, j As Long`

Comment: When i test this code, the result is always MyDateRange is "A:A"

Comment: @LiamBee It worked for me, as I've tested it, maybe it has something to do with data types used (the ones stored in the column vs. the search values)

Comment: @Takedasama I believe you are correct, something to do with the data types!

Answer (score 2):

Using `Find` is the right way to do this type of thing, you just need to get a few details right.

- Use `Set` to assign range references.  Eg `Set StartRange = ...` (and make sure to `Dim StartRange as Range`).  Ditto `EndRange` and `SearchRange`
- Specify a `After` cell.  Note that by default this is the Top Left cell of the search range, and the search begins *after* this cell.  If your StartDate happens to be in cell A1 (and another cell) then leaving as default will return the wrong result
- Limit the search range to the column of interest.
- `Dim` all your variables.  Each variaqble needs its own `As` (and use `Option Explicit`)

End result

```
Dim startrange As Range, endrange As Range, searchrange As Range
Dim LookUpColumn as Long

LookUpColumn = 2
With ws.Columns(LookupColumn)
    ' Make sure lookup column data is type Date
    Set searchrange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    searchrange.Value = searchrange .Value
    Set searchrange = Nothing

    Set StartRange = .Find(What:=CDate(StartDate), _
      After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, LookupColumn), _
      SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)

    Set EndRange = .Find(What:=CDate(EndDate), _
      After:=.Cells(1, LookupColumn), _
      SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

Set searchrange = Range(startrange, endrange)
MsgBox searchrange.Address
```

Comment: Interesting and easy to customize in case the selection has to be done upwards or downwards. Still, I believe the `LookupColumn` should be used also in the `.Cells`, if not, you may be searching in one column and define a range on another. The answer above doesn't explain how you create a range **between** StartRange and EndRange. As I understand from Liam that there should be some intermediate values captured within the range also.

Comment: @Takedasama Good point on `LookupColumn`, I've added that.  As I read the OP whats required is the first StartDate and Last EndDate.  Thats what this answer gives. Create a range with these results with `Range(StartRange, EndRange)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Ok, I've tried to get this working and I'm getting a few problems, mainly with "Type Mismatch" errors. I understand what this code is trying to do and feel that this is the best approach! Just can't get it working, I'll post how im trying to use this

Comment: @Chrisneilsen This is now giving me a range, but it's always the size of the table the data is in, including the blank spaces. I think there must be an issue with the data types. On the worksheet, it's typed as a string and Excel changes it to a date I presume. But the information that is entered in to the "Database" sheet comes from a form, so has no formatting, so Im guess it's a string? If i can make sure the data types are the same, then im sure this method will work

Comment: @Liam I've updated the answer to do two things: make sure source data is type Date, and convert the `StartDate` value to Date

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the concept of this date search for a couple of reasons..

- It makes the assumption that the dates will always be in order
- It makes the assumption that both the dates will exist in the list

Whilst these may be valid assumptions in this case, I'm sure there may be instances where this may not be the case...

I don't know the best way to do this but one alternative to consider is using the auto-filter

Something like:

```
 Sub FindDateRange()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim column As Long
Set sht = Sheet1

Dim rng As Range, inclusiveRange As Range
Dim startDate As Long, endDate As Long

column = 2

On Error GoTo Err

startDate = DateValue("02/10/2012")
endDate = DateValue("05/10/2012")

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    sht.Cells(1, column).AutoFilter Field:=column, Criteria1:=">=" & startDate, Operator:=xlAnd _
            , Criteria2:="<=" & endDate


    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, column), sht.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row, column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    sht.AutoFilterMode = False

    If rng.Address = sht.Cells(1, column).Address Then



        MsgBox Format(startDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & " - " & Format(endDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "No instances of the date range exist"

    Else

    Set inclusiveRange = sht.Range(rng.Cells(1, 1), rng.Cells(rng.Count, 1))

        MsgBox Format(startDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & " - " & Format(endDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "the range is " & rng.Address & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "inclusive range is " & inclusiveRange.Address
    End If





continue:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Exit Sub

Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    GoTo continue


End Sub
```

[image: Example2]

[image: Example1]

[image: Example3]

Comment: nice approach, But this works if the StartDate and EndDate will register once in the dateset. If the EndDate shows more than once, the range would look like (i.e. A1 : A5,A6,A7). Still, I'm sure this can be fine-tuned.

Comment: @Takedasama Did you test that theory? It didn't work like that when I tested it..... I added a screen-print to my answer.

Comment: Yup, Tested it, and got the result of your 3rd screen A2:A11,A13 (two end dates separated by ,) In that case I don't believe the range would be usable.