# Check date based on startDate and endDate

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am trying to set up a function which will be able to check dates from one sheet (sheet1) through 2 columns: startDate and endDate in Sheet2. And if there are matching then I want to copy values from one cell which is located on sheet2 into specific cell (the same row where is the cheking date) into sheet1.
 I wrote some code, but later on I've realized that my logic is not good.
I also found [this link on stackoverflow website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024182/vba-set-range-between-two-dates-using-search-function%20/)...

[my xls file - function is in the module 3 "checkDate"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/49lfqp1rdv0ga1u/test.xlsm?dl=0)

and here is the code..I need find function somehow..maybe I need to insert two iterators (2 for loops?)

```
Sub CheckDate()

Dim d1 As Date
Dim d2 As Date
Dim datumPok As Date
Dim s As String
Dim i As Long

Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LR

    d1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Glasnik").Cells(i, 2).Value

    d2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Glasnik").Cells(i, 3).Value

    With .Range("K" & i)

        datumPok = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Spisak").Cells(i, 11)

        If d1 < datumPok < d2 Then
            MsgBox "opaaa"

            s = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Glasnik").Cells(i, 4).Value

            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Spisak").Cells(i, 6).Value = s

        Else
            MsgBox "test"

        End If
     End With
Next i
End Sub
```

I am really into this..thanks guys!

Comment: Dim j As Lond? have  you run this code at all?

Comment: Sorry for this, but Dim j as Long is irrelevant. I will edit it. Sorry again

Comment: I suspect at least the line `If d1 < datumPok < d2 Then` is a big part of your problem, as you cannot use a logical statement like that in VBA. Try using `If d1 < datumPok And datumPok < d2 Then` instead, as that is the correct syntax. If your code still doesn't work (I only skimmed, looking for really obvious errors), could you try stating your problem a bit more succinctly, as it really isn't clear what you are asking, or where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Ordinary lookup with some mathematic formula was enough.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((G1>=$A$1:$A$24)*(G1<=$B$1:$B$24)),$C$1:$C$24)
```

assuming that date is in the column G1..

Thanks to all! :)